# Simplify JQuery snippet

Tags: jquery, performance

Hello experienced friends,

I would like to simplify this snippet of JQuery, it is possible?

I tried to simplify, but had no success, what i could do, was, selecting all img.main, but on hover, all of the images got the class imgHover.

```
$( "#1 button" ).hover(function() {
  $( "#1 img.main" ).toggleClass( "imgHover" );
});

$( "#2 button" ).hover(function() {
  $( "#2 img.main" ).toggleClass( "imgHover" );
});

$( "#3 button" ).hover(function() {
  $( "#3 img.main" ).toggleClass( "imgHover" );
});

$( "#4 button" ).hover(function() {
  $( "#4 img.main" ).toggleClass( "imgHover" );
});

$( "#5 button" ).hover(function() {
  $( "#5 img.main" ).toggleClass( "imgHover" );
});

$( "#6 button" ).hover(function() {
  $( "#6 img.main" ).toggleClass( "imgHover" );
});
```

Thank you

Comment: What does your html look like?

Comment: On button hover, get the id of the button and apply your toggle class to that id.

Comment: Please don't use just digits as an ID: [`ID and NAME tokens must begin with a letter ([A-Za-z]) and may be followed by any number of letters, digits ([0-9]), hyphens ("-"), underscores ("_"), colons (":"), and periods (".").`](https://www.w3.org/TR/html401/types.html#type-name)

Comment: This appears to be more fit on code [review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: I did no know that there was a code Review, Thank you i will post there and erase here.

Comment: @empiric, thank you for that!!!!

Comment: @empiric in HTML5 numeric `id` attributes are valid - although I agree they should be avoided

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a common class to the elements that currently have the 1,2,3... IDs e.g.

```
<div id="1" class="newClassName">
    <button>Click me</button>
    <img class="main" />
</div>
```

Then use generalised JQuery like this:

```
$( ".newClassName button" ).hover(function() {
    $( this ).closest(".newClassName").find("img.main").toggleClass( "imgHover" );
});
```

This will find the surrounding (newClassName) element, then find the image within that and apply the class. That way this JS will work no matter which section is being hovered.

Comment: This is spot on! love how simple it is! Cheers mate, this is where i applied it, http://codepen.io/nunoooo/pen/xOzwab

Comment: @Nunocruz No problem, happy to help :)

Comment: I would suggest using `parent()` instead of `closest()` since you already know it is the parent element and also using `children()` instead of `find()`, again since you already know the element you are looking for is a direct descendant.

Comment: @RobertoLinares Indeed, that would be a worthwhile change if it is in fact a direct parent. However the asker didn't provide HTML, so I wrote it to work in the most generic situation, my example at the top was purely speculation based on the original JS. Edit: Looking at the codepen response, I don't think the wrapper is a direct parent.

Comment: I'm sorry for not providing the HTML right at first, but the generic response is the one that i was looking, because it apply's anywhere!
@Roberto & DBS why the use of parent() and children() is better? for performance?

Comment: @Nunocruz I was under the impression `children` and `parent` were significantly faster, but after a quick search around I don't see much difference at all. Generally I'd just use whichever one is more fitting to your situation, e.g. if you know you're only looking one level up or down, use `children`/`parent` otherwise stick to `find`/`closest`.